# Brownian motion and Durret book

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have a problem to understand the following simple definition in Durrett book:     Brownian motion and martingales in analysis. What does the following mean: $T = \inf \{t: B_t \in A\}$. It seems to me that $T$ depends on random variable $\omega$ in the measure space $\Omega$, so, my question is the previous definition indeed: $T(\omega) = \inf \{t: B_t(\omega) \in A\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: assuming $B_t$ is a random variable, $T$ is also a random variable, and the inf is done pointwise with respect to the sample space.

Comment: Indeed, $B_t$ is a Brohnian motion.